# What is the production url for Ionic 6

Tags: api, ionic-framework, https

I just started an ionic app and dev spins up `http:localhost:8081`. I will be hitting an api that needs to whitelist the apps url. What will that be? `https:localhost:8081`?

Answer (score 1):

You most likely need to whitelist the IP adress of the app. Which is going to change depending on the phone it is installed on.

For your usecase you most likely want to have a server communicating with both the app and api so you can use it's IP address to whitelist.